# Cannot find Module in "protractor'

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am trying to get started with page object model in Protractor, but i am always getting "module not found" error.
Please guide.

My Folder structure:

```
pages
   --- homePage.js
spec.js
conf.js
```

spec.js

```
'use strict';

var HomePage = require('pages/homePage.js');

describe('Login cases', function() {
  var page;
  it('Login without username & password', function() {
    page= new HomePage();
    page.mainLoginButton.click();
    page.popupLoginButton.click();
    expect(page.errMsgUsername.getText()).toEqual('Please enter valid Email or Mobile Number');
  });
});
```

conf.js

```
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['spec.js']
}
```

homePage.js

```
'use strict';

var HomePage = function () {
  browser.get('https://www.mobikwik.com');
  browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
};

 HomePage.prototype = Object.create({}, {
    mainLoginButton: { get: function () { return by.id('qa-mbkLogin')); 

}},
    popupLoginButton: { get: function () { return by.xpath('//*

[@id="loginInfo"]/div[3]/p/button')); }},
    errMsgUsername: { get: function () { by.xpath('//*

[@id="loginInfo"]/div[1]/span')); }},
  }}
});

module.exports = HomePage;
```

I am always getting cannot find module error. What need to be changed?

Comment: Where are you seeing this error? Is protractor installed globally and accessible on your $PATH? Or is this happening after protractor has initialized and read your config file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try:

```
var HomePage = require('./pages/homePage.js');
```

See if that helps.

You're also referencing `"spec.js"` in your config but the file is called `"specs.js"`.

Comment: this path worked, but logic is not clear since pages folder and spec.js are in same path.

Comment: The `"./"` references the current folder, whereas `"../"` would reference the parent. If you omit this, `require` is attempting to open the path on your root directory.